# How can I change these colors in CSS instead of applying style in the Markup?

Tags: css

How can I change these colors in CSS instead of applying style in the Markup?
Note: Each one of them has a different color!!!

```css
ul li a{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
ul li a::before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--clr);
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 8px solid var(--clr);
  transition: 1s;
}

ul li a:hover::before{
  /* Marque both of them */
  width: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 25px var(--clr));
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li style="--clr:#00ade1">
   <a href="#" data-text = '&nbsp;Home'>&nbsp;Home&nbsp;</a>
   </li>
   <li style="--clr:#ff6493">
   <a href="#" data-text ='&nbsp;Services'>&nbsp;Services&nbsp;</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is --clr applied to? why not just use CSS classes :/ also there is such a thing as padding and margin, packing with `&nbsp;` makes for some ugly code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use CSS classes?

Comment: I agree with Lawrence Chreone, those ```&nbsp;``` really make the code very unclean and ugly.
 
Here it is the full Project:
codepen.io/rbsn-mnz/pen/QWQdZOV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the inline styles from the markup, use CSS classes instead. They are cleaner, easier to maintain and easier to override than inline styles.

```css
/* CSS classes are denoted by a leading dot (.)
   and are applied to the HTML with the class attribute. */
.blue {--clr:#00ade1; }
.red { --clr:#ff6493; }

ul li a{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
ul li a::before{
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  color: var(--clr);
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 8px solid var(--clr);
  transition: 1s;
}

ul li a:hover::before{
  /* Marque both of them */
  width: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 25px var(--clr));
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="blue">
   <a href="#" data-text = '&nbsp;Home'>&nbsp;Home&nbsp;</a>
   </li>
   <li class="red">
   <a href="#" data-text ='&nbsp;Services'>&nbsp;Services&nbsp;</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It makes sense, and how about thos ungly ```'&nbsp;``` how can I avoid them in the context above?

Comment: It is an "HTML Entity" for a non-breaking space (nbsp). If you only want one space, you don't  need that escape entity code and can just manually insert a space character. If you want more than one, you either need to wrap them in a `pre` element or use the entity code.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the ":nth-child" pseudo-class

```
ul li:nth-child(1) {color: #00ade1; }
ul li:nth-child(2) {color: #ff6493; }
```

Comment: It is about a hover effects on text:
https://codepen.io/rbsn-mnz/pen/QWQdZOV